# Is there a way to check if an istream was opened in binary mode?

Tags: c++, standard-library, iostream

I'm using an istream which could be stringstream, ifstream or a user-defined stream type and I need to know if, in the case of an ifstream, it was not opened in binary mode (so I can throw an exception). I have tried the following method:

```
if ((_is.flags() & ios::binary) == 0)
    throw exception(...)
```

but no exception is ever thrown. The test fails in this case because _is.flags() returns 0x201 and ios::binary is 0x20. Is there a way to find out if a stream was opened in text mode?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

flags() returns [ios_base::fmtflags](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios_base/fmtflags.html) which is formatting flags, whereas binary is an [ios_base::openmode](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios_base/openmode.html) flag. I'm not sure if there is a way to find these out once the stream is already open. I was thinking that maybe there was a virtual member of the streambuf class that could help, but there doesn't really seem to be.

Comment: I was afraid that was the case.

Comment: It's a shame the committee had never rectified this.  I just spent a day searching for some unit test failures.  The bug was _not_ in the code being tested, but the test itself, which passed in a text stream instead of a binary one.  I just want to add an assert to remind anyone using the code (including future me) to ensure the stream is opened in the proper mode.

Answer (score 7):

Nope, there is no way to test this.