# How to get boost::iostream to operate in a mode comparable to std::ios::binary?

Tags: c++, iostream, eof, boost-iostreams

I have the following question on `boost::iostreams`. If someone is familiar with writing filters, I would actually appreciate your advices / help.

I am writing a pair of multichar filters, that work with `boost::iostream::filtering_stream` as *data compressor and decompressor.*
I started from writing a compressor, picked up some algorithm from lz-family and now am working on a decompressor.

*In a couple of words, my compressor splits data into packets, which are encoded separately and then flushed to my file.*

When I have to restore data from my file (in programming terms, receive a `read(byte_count)` request), I have to read a **full** packed block, bufferize it, unpack it and only then give the requested number of bytes. *I've implemented this logic, but right now I'm struggling with **the following problem:***

---

When my data is packed, any symbols can appear in the output file. And I have troubles when reading file, which contains symbol `(hex 1A, char 26)` using `boost::iostreams::read(...., size)`.

If I was using `std::ifstream`, for example, I would have set a `std::ios::binary` mode and then this symbol could be read simply.

*Any way to achieve the same when implementing a `boost::iostream` filter which uses `boost::iostream::read` routine to read char sequence?*

---

*Some code here:*

```
   // Compression
   // -----------
   filtering_ostream out;
   out.push(my_compressor());
   out.push(file_sink("file.out"));

   // Compress the 'file.in' to 'file.out'
   std::ifstream stream("file.in");
   out << stream.rdbuf();


   // Decompression
   // -------------
   filtering_istream in;
   in.push(my_decompressor());
   in.push(file_source("file.out"));

   std::string res;
   while (in) {
      std::string t;

      // My decompressor wants to retrieve the full block from input (say, 4096 bytes)
      // but instead retrieves 150 bytes because meets '1A' char in the char sequence

      // That obviously happens because file should be read as a binary one, but
      // how do I state that?
      std::getline(in, t); // <--------- The error happens here

      res += t;
   }
```

Comment: a compilable test case always beat wall of text.

Comment: I ran into a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224234/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-an-istream-was-opened-in-binary-mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer for reading file as binary :

specify `ios_base::binary` when opening file stream.

[MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zek0beca(VS.80).aspx)

Comment: That looks fine. But do I have any option to, for example force my `filter` to work only when the corresponding device is in `binary` mode? Or this can't be checked?

Comment: what are you referring in case of "binary mode devices" ?