# C, C++: Howto know whether a file is opened in binary mode?

Tags: c++, c, file, io

Given a 'FILE*' handle or an ifstream object, how is it possible to detect whether it has been opened in binary mode?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224234/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-an-istream-was-opened-in-binary-mode) might help you.

Comment: In [`glibc-2.21/libio/fileops.c:303`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=libio/fileops.c;h=b997e4bc5539a8416212d8ab011b620862347a8f;hb=4e42b5b8f89f0e288e68be7ad70f9525aebc2cff#l303) one can see that the 'b' mode is ignored, so it is impossible to detect it.

Comment: I disagree that this is a duplicate of the particular question linked.  There are other operating systems than Linux, and there are other C runtimes than glibc.  The linked question's answer uses `fcntl()` to get the open flags, but `fcntl` is a non-standard function, and in particular it doesn't exist on Windows platforms - where the binary/non-binary file mode has significant impacts.  The C standard requires support of binary and non-binary `FILE` modes, but doesn't mandate a way to discover the mode from a given `FILE` structure.