# std::basic_ofstream<std::uint8_t> write fails at __check_facet()

Tags: c++, locale, ofstream, ostream

I'm trying to write some binary data to a file using `std::basic_ofstream<std::uint8_t>`, but it throws `bad_cast` at __check_facet(). I guess somehow I should `imbue()` the stream with a locale that has `std::codecvt<std::uint8_t, char, std::mbstate_t>`, but I don't really know how to do that.
My motivation is that I would like to differentiate the stream operators that writes binary data (std::uint8_t version) from the operators that writes textual data (char).

It fails when the `write` calls `__check_facet()` and it has null pointer, so throws `bad_cast`.

```
(gdb) l
45    template<typename _Facet>
46      inline const _Facet&
47      __check_facet(const _Facet* __f)
48      {
49        if (!__f)
50           __throw_bad_cast();
51        return *__f;
52      }

#0  std::__check_facet<std::codecvt<unsigned char, char, __mbstate_t> > (__f=0x0) at /usr/include/c++/7/bits/basic_ios.h:50
#1  0x000055555555a1c0 in std::basic_filebuf<unsigned char, std::char_traits<unsigned char> >::xsputn (this=0x7fffffffdc38, __s=0x7fffffffdc2f "*X\311uUUU", __n=1)
    at /usr/include/c++/7/bits/fstream.tcc:731
#2  0x0000555555557301 in std::basic_streambuf<unsigned char, std::char_traits<unsigned char> >::sputn (this=0x7fffffffdc38, __s=0x7fffffffdc2f "*X\311uUUU", __n=1) at /usr/include/c++/7/streambuf:451
#3  0x000055555555693c in std::basic_ostream<unsigned char, std::char_traits<unsigned char> >::_M_write (this=0x7fffffffdc30, __s=0x7fffffffdc2f "*X\311uUUU", __n=1) at /usr/include/c++/7/ostream:313
#4  0x00005555555560b0 in std::basic_ostream<unsigned char, std::char_traits<unsigned char> >::write (this=0x7fffffffdc30, __s=0x7fffffffdc2f "*X\311uUUU", __n=1)
    at /usr/include/c++/7/bits/ostream.tcc:196
#5  0x0000555555555cb1 in main () at test.cpp:7
```

```
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::basic_ofstream<std::uint8_t> ofs("test.bin", std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::binary);
    std::uint8_t x = 42;
    ofs.write(&x, 1);
    ofs.close();
}
```

The problem comes only on linux with g++ (currently using 7.3.0), on windows with msvc it works fine.

Edit:

In the end, I would like to achieve separate overloaded stream operators for binary and text output. Something like this:

```
#include <fstream>

struct A
{
    std::uint32_t number = 10;
};

std::ofstream& operator<<(std::ofstream& s, const A& a)
{
    s << "The number is: " << a.number;
    return s;
}

std::basic_ofstream<std::uint8_t>& operator<<(std::basic_ofstream<std::uint8_t>& s, const A& a)
{
    s.write(reinterpret_cast<const std::uint8_t*>(&a.number), 4);
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    std::ofstream textFile("test.txt");
    textFile << a;
    textFile.close();

    std::basic_ofstream<std::uint8_t> binaryFile("test.bin", std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::binary);
    binaryFile << a;
    binaryFile.close();
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: The C++ library does not provide localte/facets for, what is effectively, an `unsigned char` stream. The C++ specification does not require the C++ library to do that. You don't need a non-standard `uint8_t`-based file stream object to do this. Just a plain, garden-variety, `std::oifstream` will do just fine.

Comment: Also, if you're just wanting to do binary file IO, just use `write()` with a normal `std::ofstream`.

Comment: My goal is to have stream operators that are for writing binary data and that are for text (for `std::cout` for example). I might get the wrong idea of implementing it by using `std::basic_ofstream<std::uint8_t>`. Could you recommend something to achieve this?

Comment: @face again, just use a standard `std::ofstream` class (aka `std::basic_ofstream<char>`). You are already constructing with the `binary` flag enabled, simply type cast your data to `char*` when passing it to `std::ofstream::write()`, eg: `std::ofstream ofs("test.bin", std::ios_base::binary); ofs.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&x), sizeof(x));`

Comment: I understand that it works with a simple `std::ofstream`, but I would like 2 operator for a class, one for binary, one for text. I can't use two operators with `std::ofstream` and according to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224234/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-an-istream-was-opened-in-binary-mode) I can't decide that the stream was binary or not, so I can't do it with a single operator.

Comment: Here's an idea: Write your own "binary stream" class that wraps a std::ofstream (or even just a plain C FILE* for better performance) and overload `operator<<` for the types you want to be insertable into your custom binary stream. If the file is intended to be read by different computers, you'll have consider endianness of the encoded data.