# std::basic_fstream<unsigned char> doesn't work on Linux

Tags: c++, linux

I'm getting a failure on Linux when calling the `read()` function on `basic_fstream<unsigned char>` stream:

```
basic_fstream<unsigned char> fs;
basic_string<unsigned char> buf(1000, '\0');
fs.open( "/tmp/file.txt", ios::in | ios::binary);
fs.read( &buf[0], 1000);
```

I traced where it throws: in function `__check_facet(const _Facet* __f)` it throws `__throw_bad_cast()` because `__f` is NULL. The `__check_facet()` in turn is called from `underflow()`, with `_M_codecvt` as the parameter (which is NULL and causes the failure).

The system's locale is UTF8, the code is compiled with --std=c++14. On Windows this works OK.

Can it be corrected somehow?

Comment: *The C++ library does not provide localte/facets for, what is effectively, an unsigned char stream. The C++ specification does not require the C++ library to do that.* - [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55444139/stdbasic-ofstreamstduint8-t-write-fails-at-check-facet) might bring some clarity.

Comment: rawrex, thanks for the link. That is, basically, the only solution is using a standard std::fstream?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604431/c-reading-unsigned-char-from-file-stream/604505#604505)

Comment: @AlBerger I liked the idea of "*your own "binary stream" class*" by [@Emile Cormier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/245265/emile-cormier) in the comments to that thread.

Comment: rawrex, yes I saw that comment. I meant that in the wrapper eventually it should be std::ofstream or even C FILE*?

Comment: alagner, thanks, your link is useful too. Seems that basic_fstream<unsigned char> is no-go on Linux.

Comment: Remy, I already wanted to write my own facet, but your solution is much simpler. Please post it as an answer.

Comment: @AlBerger posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard library is not required to provide facets or locales for `unsigned char`. The standard streams are designed only with `char` (and `wchar_t`) in mind.

I would suggest using the standard `std::ifstream` instead. You can read binary data with it, and store it into an `unsigned char` buffer. You should consider using the standard `std::vector` container instead of `std::basic_string` for that buffer.

Try this instead:

```cpp
ifstream fs("/tmp/file.txt", ios::binary);
vector<unsigned char> buf(1000);
fs.read( reinterpret_cast<char*>(&buf[0]), 1000);
```

This will work equally on all platforms.